Como convertir celda con texto separado por comas en google sheets, a tabla en google docs usando appscritpt
les explico mi dudaa, tengo un formulario hecho en google forms que tiene un check list, los resultados de este formulario se guardan en una hoja de google sheets, hice un script que genera un archivo pdf que se envía por correo electrónico cuando el ckecklist no está completo, el formulario pone el checklist en una celda como texto separado por comas. Al llamar esa celda en el documento para crear el archivo pdf se pega la información sin problema como texto separado por comas, pero quiero que en el documento cada una de las opciones del ckecklist aparezca dentro de una celda distinta, como si fuera una lista. Cómo podría hacerlo? Qué instrucción puedo utilizar en appscript? Intenté hacer un split dentro de la hoja de calculo, guardando la info en otra hoja y llamando dentro del documento cada una de las celdas, pero me marca error al correr el script.
function enviarPDF(e) {
  var respuestas = e.namedValues;
  var analista = respuestas['Analista que hace la revisión'][0];
  var tiposala = respuestas['Tipo de Sala'][0];
  var nomsala1touch = respuestas['Nombre de la sala 1Touch revisada'][0];
  var nomsalacm = respuestas['Nombre de la sala Casual Meeting revisada'][0];
  var funsala1touch = respuestas['Funcionamiento de la sala 1Touch'][0];
  var funcsalacm = respuestas['Funcionamiento de la sala Casual Meeting'][0];
  var observaciones = respuestas['Observaciones de la sala'][0];
  var evidencia1touch = respuestas['Evidencia de la sala 1Touch'] [0]
  var evidenciacm = respuestas['Evidencia de la sala Casual Meeting'] [0]
  var errorsala1touch = respuestas ['Funcionalidad de la sala 1Touch'] [0]
  var errorsalacm = respuestas ['Funcionalidad de la sala Casual Meeting'] [0]

  const idPlantilla='1Ow4oTDEk2x91E2r';
  const nameCarpeta='Revisión';
  const email='yyy@xxx.com';

  var carpeta=DriveApp.getFoldersByName(nameCarpeta);
  var archivoPlantilla=DriveApp.getFileById(idPlantilla);
  var copiaArchivo=archivoPlantilla.makeCopy(nameCarpeta);
  var idCopia=copiaArchivo.getId();
  

 
  if (tiposala === "1Touch"){
  var documento = DocumentApp.openById(idCopia);
  var cuerpo = documento.getBody();
  var Equipos1t=e.namedValues;
  var item0= Equipos1t ['item0'][0];
  var item1= Equipos1t ['item1'][0];
  var item2= Equipos1t ['item2'][0];
  var item3= Equipos1t ['item3'][0];
  var item4= Equipos1t ['item4'][0];
  var item5= Equipos1t ['item5'][0];
  var item6= Equipos1t ['item6'][0];
  var item7= Equipos1t ['item7'][0];
  var item8= Equipos1t ['item8'][0];
  var item9= Equipos1t ['item0'][0];
  var item10= Equipos1t ['item10'][0];
  var item11= Equipos1t ['item11'][0];
  var item12= Equipos1t ['item12'][0];
  var item13= Equipos1t ['item13'][0];
  cuerpo.replaceText("//sala//", nomsala1touch);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//observaciones//", observaciones);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//item0//", item0[0]);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//item1//", item1[0]);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//item2//", item2[0]);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//item3//", item3[0]);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//item4//", item4[0]);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//item5//", item5[0]);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//item6//", item6[0]);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//item7//", item7[0]);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//item8//", item8[0]);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//item9//", item9[0]);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//item10//", item10[0]);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//item11//", item11[0]);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//item12//", item12[0]);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//item13//", item13[0]);
  cuerpo.replaceText("//evidencia//", evidencia1touch);
  
  documento.saveAndClose();

  var pdfBlob = copiaArchivo.getAs(MimeType.PDF);}

  if (errorsala1touch ==="La sala tiene algún faltante o no funciona al 100%")
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, 'Problema detectado en sala 1Touch', 'Se anexa el informe de la revisión.', {
    attachments: [pdfBlob]
    });

